# Only instantiate class from within itself

Tags: php

I am looking for a way where you can call a static method in a class, which will create an instance of itself. I would like it so it isn't possible to instantiate the class outside of itself. I have tried this, but I get an error saying **Cannot instantiate abstract class** (Which I assumed would happen).

```
abstract class Test {

    public function __construct($item){

    }

    public static function from($item){
        return new Test($item);
    }

    public function testFunc(){
        // Do some stuff
        return $this;
    }

}
```

It's usage would look something like this:

```
// Valid
Test::from($myItem)->testFunc();

// Invalid
(new Test($myItem))->testFunc();
```

Is there any way to do something like this?

Comment: It seems that you are trying to implement a Singleton for this class, is that it?

Comment: Make the constructor `private`, not the class `abstract`.

Comment: Read about [singleton class](http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html)  design pattern

Comment: See Baba's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553142/when-we-should-make-the-constructor-private-why-php

Comment: @Marvin Ahh, that looks like it works better than the singleton....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the constructor private and then return the instance.. Something like this:

```
class Test {

    private function __construct($item){

    }

    public static function from($item){
        return new static($item);
    }

}
```

Now you would create new instances only like this:

```
$new_object = Test::from('something');
```

Comment: This looks like it will do!