# Add theme support for post thumbnail isn't working from theme class

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a theme class that I bootstrap my theme in and add the theme support but the featured image meta box isn't appearing.

Inside the class file:

```
class WCS_THEME {

    private function __construct() {
        $this->setup_hooks();
    }

    // Singleton design code here

    protected function setup_hooks() {
        add_action( 'after_theme_setup', [ $this, 'setup_theme' ] );
    }

    public function setup_theme() {
        add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    }
}
\WCS_THEME\Inc\WCS_THEME::get_instance();
```

Inside functions.php:

```
require WCS_DIR_PATH . '/inc/classes/class-wcs-theme.php';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of  all, simply replace

```
\WCS_THEME\Inc\WCS_THEME::get_instance();
```

with

```
$instance=new \WCS_THEME\Inc\WCS_THEME();
```

Also,
it is a bit strange that you don't get fatal error with the code above.
Turn debugging to TRUE to see PHP warnings.

I believe there is some problem with WCS_DIR_PATH.
Print full path with

```
echo WCS_DIR_PATH . '/inc/classes/class-wcs-theme.php';
```

to make sure it is a correct path to your file.

Comment: I replace the line above but I get an error because the class has a private constructor. It's strange that this class is giving me issued because my styles are enqueued in a class that works in the theme. :(

Comment: Yes, you can remove private from there if it is not needed. or you can use get_instanse method given in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12553217/701666

Comment: The featured image section still isn't showing up :(

Comment: I don't see whole structure there, but if you can't solve it, then why not to use add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); in your functions.php ?  Just paste that single line there and that's all.

Comment: I put this in the functions.php:

`function wcs_setup() {
 add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
}
add_action( 'after_theme_setup', 'wcs_setup' );`

But it still isn't showing up. Any advice?

Comment: that should be after_setup_theme, not after_theme_setup