# PHP: don't want to show __construct or any variable inside the _construction function

Tags: php

I created a class with a constructor (`__construct()`), but I don't want anyone to be able to access it. How can I do that? Thank you very much!

Edit 1:

For more detail: I created a class:

```
<?php
class test{
    function __construct()
    {
        $a=1;
    }
}
$t = new test;
$t->//here's the problem
?>
```

In my editor, when press $t->, the code hint shows the ('_*construct()') and ('$a') too.
I want to ask: Can someone else can acces ('$a') or ('*_construct()').
How can I prevent that,

Comment: You cannot have a class without it beeing constructed. If you don't want to run any code on object construction, simply don't use a constructor.

Comment: Can I ask why you would want this behavior? What is your reasoning behind this request?

Answer (score 2):

Just make the constructor `private`

```
class Test {
    private function __construct() {}
}
```

Comment: Then no one can use the class, it's just a block of bytes.

Comment: But you *did* answer the question.

Comment: @jdersen its commonly used in the singleton pattern, static methods of the class can create instances.

Comment: @jdersen - Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079/in-a-php5-class-when-does-a-private-constructor-get-called) for an example usage.

Comment: Indeed; this would be used in the [singleton pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203336/creating-the-singleton-design-pattern-in-php5).

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks. Learn something new every day :)

Comment: the static method which creates the instantiation will still have the constructor itself, because of returning self. Simply var_dump the static method will expose the same information, as dumping the class instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't let any access the constructor function for your class - no one will be able to use that class as they will not be able to instantiate it.

In any case, if they have your class file they will be able to look at the source code and see the constructor.